# Issue with react-dom when deploying on heroku Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./lib/ReactDOM

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, react-dom

I have a create-react-app on heroku. When I try to deploy a change to production it is failing and giving me the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./lib/ReactDOM in /tmp/build_a87ef5601c25702212bff26dba1f999c/node_modules/react-dom
```

However, it is successful when I do `npm run build`. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "16.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^1.0.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "detect-port": "1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "filesize": "3.3.0",
    "find-cache-dir": "0.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "gzip-size": "3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.2",
    "jest": "16.0.2",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "path-exists": "2.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.0.0",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "recursive-readdir": "2.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "strip-ansi": "3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.6",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "jsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/FileStub.js",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/CSSStub.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/(build|docs|node_modules)/"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

I tried removing the node_modules file and re-installing [per the advice here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/901) but I continue to get the same error. I have buildpack set up with heroku and was able to successfully deploy the app last week. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include the code which is causing this?

Comment: How do you import ReactDOM in your code?

Comment: in my index.js file I import ReactDOM `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` and then use `ReactDom.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root')`